# Change properties at component decorator Angular 2 from class

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to change template after some action happens

```
@Component({
  ... 
  template: this.myTemplate
})

export class App {
  myTemplate: = 'Here is first template';

  // Replace templates
  public changeTempate() {
    myTemplate = 'Here is second template';
  }
```

How to make this code work?

Comment: What exactly is your use case here? There's lots of possible options, depending on what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I want to change template (html)

Comment: That's not a use case. I'm talking about the context for what you're trying to achieve here. Let me explain - technically speaking what you asked for is impossible because Angular compiles templates either JIT (just in time) or AOT (ahead of time) - before your class logic ever executes. BUT you have options in the form of binding `[innerHTML]` or conditionally showing two components using `*ngIf`. But I can't recommend one to you unless I know the actual use case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally It was made in Angular 2.3.0
Here is simple sample:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, Input, Output, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'person',
  //template will NOT be inherited 
  template: `<h4>Person: {{name}}</h4>`
})
export class Person {
  @Input() name; //will be inherited
  //  @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter(); //will be inherited
  //  clicked() { //will be inherited
  //    this.onClick.emit(this.name);
  //  }
  @HostBinding('style.color') color = 'red';  //will be inherited

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) //will be inherited 
  onClick(e){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'employee',
  template: `
    <h4>Employee: {{name}}, id: {{id}}</h4>
  `
})
export class Employee extends Person {
  @Input() id; // new

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) // overridden
  onClick(e) { 
    console.log(`${this.name}-${this.id}`);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <person name="John"></person>
      <employee name="Tom" id="45231"></employee>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, Person, Employee ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For more information please read

> https://medium.com/@gerard.sans/angular-2-new-features-in-angular-2-3-f2e73f16a09e#.33fk3molt